# make the series d3 graph chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

[image: Chart]

I trying to display a d3 linechart. I've a problem - I cannot stop the date from repeating. How can I stop the date keep repeating? I only want to show two columns(17/12/2013 and 18/12/2013) based on the JSON data reflected below. Or what do I need to do so the first tickmark would show 17/12/2013 and the last one would show 18/12/2013?

```
[
  {
    "key": "Excited",
    "values": [ [1387212490000, 0], [1387298890000 , 10] ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Sad",
    "values": [ [1387212490000, 20], [1387298890000 , 50] ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Angry",
    "values": [ [1387212490000, 30], [1387298890000 , 30] ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Happy",
    "values": [ [1387212490000, 40], [1387298890000 , 70] ]
  }
]
```

Below is the JS script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        d3.json('sales.json', function(data) {

            nv.addGraph(function() {
                var chart = nv.models.lineChart().x(function(d) {
                    return d[0]
                }).y(function(d) {
                    return d[1] 
                }).color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

                chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d))
                });

                //chart.xScale(d3.time.scale());

                d3.select('#nvd3 svg').datum(data).transition().duration(500).call(chart);

                nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

                return chart;
            });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show enough code so it may be difficult to debug...

Anyway, try this and I'm working on an example to prove it...

```
chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d))
  })
  .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added .ticks(d3.time.days, 1). it's doesn't work. And honestly this is all the code I have to generate the line chart.

Answer (score -2):

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    barWidth = Math.floor(width / 19) - 1;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([barWidth / 2, width - barWidth / 2]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("right")
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return Math.round(d / 1e6) + "M"; });

// An SVG element with a bottom-right origin.
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// A sliding container to hold the bars by birthyear.
var birthyears = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "birthyears");

// A label for the current year.
var title = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .text(2000);

d3.csv("population.csv", function(error, data) {

  // Convert strings to numbers.
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.people = +d.people;
    d.year = +d.year;
    d.age = +d.age;
  });

  // Compute the extent of the data set in age and years.
  var age1 = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.age; }),
      year0 = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.year; }),
      year1 = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.year; }),
      year = year1;

  // Update the scale domains.
  x.domain([year1 - age1, year1]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.people; })]);

  // Produce a map from year and birthyear to [male, female].
  data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.year; })
      .key(function(d) { return d.year - d.age; })
      .rollup(function(v) { return v.map(function(d) { return d.people; }); })
      .map(data);

  // Add an axis to show the population values.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll("g")
    .filter(function(value) { return !value; })
      .classed("zero", true);

  // Add labeled rects for each birthyear (so that no enter or exit is required).
  var birthyear = birthyears.selectAll(".birthyear")
      .data(d3.range(year0 - age1, year1 + 1, 5))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "birthyear")
      .attr("transform", function(birthyear) { return "translate(" + x(birthyear) + ",0)"; });

  birthyear.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(birthyear) { return data[year][birthyear] || [0, 0]; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", -barWidth / 2)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .attr("y", y)
      .attr("height", function(value) { return height - y(value); });

  // Add labels to show birthyear.
  birthyear.append("text")
      .attr("y", height - 4)
      .text(function(birthyear) { return birthyear; });

  // Add labels to show age (separate; not animated).
  svg.selectAll(".age")
      .data(d3.range(0, age1 + 1, 5))
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "age")
      .attr("x", function(age) { return x(year - age); })
      .attr("y", height + 4)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .text(function(age) { return age; });

  // Allow the arrow keys to change the displayed year.
  window.focus();
  d3.select(window).on("keydown", function() {
    switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
      case 37: year = Math.max(year0, year - 10); break;
      case 39: year = Math.min(year1, year + 10); break;
    }
    update();
  });

  function update() {
    if (!(year in data)) return;
    title.text(year);

    birthyears.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x(year1) - x(year)) + ",0)");

    birthyear.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(birthyear) { return data[year][birthyear] || [0, 0]; })
      .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("height", function(value) { return height - y(value); });
  }
});
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.y.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.y.axis line {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.y.axis .zero line {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.title {
  font: 300 78px Helvetica Neue;
  fill: #666;
}

.birthyear,
.age {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.birthyear {
  fill: #fff;
}

rect {
  fill-opacity: .6;
  fill: #e377c2;
}

rect:first-child {
  fill: #1f77b4;
}
```